# How to pass value for example Login Data into Profle in react navigation 5?

Tags: react-native

I have trouble passing value such username value and other data into profile screen in react navigation. Let say i have Login page & profile page like this.

Login.js

```
export default class LoginScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    }
}

_login = async () => {
    if (userInfo.username == this.state.username && userInfo.password == this.state.password) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem('isLoggedIn', '1');
        this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeApp',{
            Username: 'Deni'
        });
    } else {
        alert('Password kamu salah')
    }
}
....
```

And Profile.js how to get the data. I have tried getParam, this.props.navigation.getParams none of them works or thrown error. Please help thanks

I have tried using this method in react navigation example.. but still failed. its said route is not defined or params is not defined.

```
const { itemId } = route.params;
  const { otherParam } = route.params;
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Details Screen</Text>
      <Text>itemId: {JSON.stringify(itemId)}</Text>
      <Text>otherParam: {JSON.stringify(otherParam)}</Text>
      <Button
        title="Go to Details... again"
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.push('Details', {
            itemId: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
          })
```

Comment: is this a class component? for function component use ```const Profile = ({ route, navigation }) => ...```

Comment: Are you using this.props.route and is it a screen component? Add how you're accessing the route.

Comment: @juniues, actually im using class component for profile, is somehow i should change it into function component. is there no other way using as class component. im still newbie.. kinda please help